# Plotting a coordinate system with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, coordinate-systems

Generally I like the look of gnuplot plots. However I have to prepare a plot for a group of people who have only ever seen old style/traditional x-y coordinate systems with x=0 and y=0 axes. In order not to confuse them, I would stick to their preferred style.

How do I achieve this in gnuplot?

I found `set xzeroaxis` which gives me the x-axis. (similar for the y-axis). Still I need to:

- get rid of the frame
- put the tic labels/numbers on the x/y-axis
- have an arrowhead at the end of the axis

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
set border 0          # remove frame
set xtics axis        # place tics on axis rather than on border
set ytics axis
set ticscale 0        # [optional] labels only, no tics
set xtics add ("" 0)  # suppress origin label that lies on top of axis
set ytics add ("" 0)  # suppress origin label that lies on top of axis
#
# if arrows are wanted only in the positive direction
set arrow 1 from 0,0 to graph 1, first 0 filled head
set arrow 2 from 0,0 to first 0, graph 1 filled head
#
# if arrows in both directions from the origin are wanted
set arrow 3 from 0,0 to graph 0, first 0 filled head
set arrow 4 from 0,0 to first 0, graph 0 filled head

plot f(x)
```

[image]